# Multithreading logic

Tags: multithreading, process, logic, mutex

Multihreading is way over me. I do not ask for a specific code, instead I'd like you to help me on the logical structure of my problem.

We have a restaurant with only 2 waiters, which are taking orders from customers instantly meaning that as soon as they are free (not serving) they take the order from the customer who is in front of the line, and they process (serve them) these orders randomly (in a time range, not instantly). Customers are in line, and whichever waiter is not serving at that moment, they take their orders.

I have a function called `GetInLine()` which is a generator of the customers, it just uses `Sleep()` function before each customer is being added to the line.

I have a function called `TakeOrders()` which (supposedly) takes orders from customers. The problem is, in that function I have a function call made `ServeCostumer()` which instantly serves customer. If I make that function `Sleep()` then it sleeps and serves the customer but what I want is of course multitasking/threading, it should be like:

- customer 1 came
- waiter 1 took order
- customer 2 came
- waiter 2 took order
- 3 came
- waiter 1 served customer 1
- customer 4 came
- waiter 2 served customer 2

Mainly what I ask is, can you help me visualize this in a code level? I mean

takeorders...
lock here
unlock here

call this and that
etc..

something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of the problem seems to be that you need two seperate actions, occuring at different times.

1. 2 waiters immediately serving customers(which takes time)
2. Customers being added to the queue at random times.

I would argue that a mutex is probably overkill here. If you really want to include a locking mechanism, you could add a switch called hasBeenServed to the customers, which, before serving the customer, is checked and then flipped by the waiter if it is false. If it is true, then go to next customer.

In terms of threads, the easiest solution would probably be to have the following threads:

1. waiter 1
2. waiter 2
3. customer line

and then kick them all off at once. I'm no multithreading expert, but this is probably how I would approach it.